# Restrict event listeners of elements in HTML

Tags: html, dom

Is it possible for an HTML element (DOM node) to have only a single event listener always?(meaning it should not further be possible to attach secondary events apart from the predefined (first) event listener).

Example :

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="I HAVE ONLY ONE EVENT LISTENER" onclick="one_and_only_eventhandler()"/>
```

then it should not be possible to add secondary events using addEventListener/attachEvent/Onclick property further.

OR say it the other way a HTML element (DOM node) should only listen to its first event listener and should not listen to secondary events.

Comment: Per event type, yes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event.stopImmediatePropagation

Comment: @Kevin B, event.stopImmediatePropogation does indeed prevent other event listeners but to do so that should happen inside the default event listener; but what if the added event listener executes first before the default one. so to make it work the inline callback specified using onclick should be made to call first so that event.stopImmediatePropogation can be used

Comment: That is correct, it would have to be first. I didn't say it was an elegant or fool proof solution, it's just.. "possible".

Comment: @Kevin B, Can you explain how to make the inline callback to be called first

Comment: No, i'm sure you can find that somewhere online, i don't deal with inline attribute events.

Comment: @Kevin B, Okay thanks for providing hints

Answer (score 0):

You can't really prevent that since most events go through the capture phase first and code could register an event listener on the document level capturing clicks long before they reach the inline handler.

And inline handlers are generally discouraged anyway. What you're trying to do sounds either like you're "fighting" against other javascript code or that your program design relies on something that DOM events are not designed to support. Either case would be very fragile.